# Correct way to use ngFor inside mat-cell

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to display the roleName of User in Roles column using mat-table

**User.ts**

```js
export const User = [{
    firstName: 'User',
    lastName: '1',
    roles: [{id: '1', roleName: 'first Role'},
        {id: '2', roleName: 'second Role'}]
}, {
    firstName: 'User',
    lastName: '2',
    roles: [{id: '1', roleName: 'third Role'},
        {id: '2', roleName: 'fourth Role'}]
}];
```

**UserDisplay.html**

```html
<section>
  <mat-table class="matTable" [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> First Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.firstName}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="lastName">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Last Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.lastName}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="roles">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Roles </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.roleName}}
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>

  </mat-table>
</section>
```

**user.component.ts**

```js
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
    this.displayedColumns = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'roles'];
    this.dataSource.data = this.User;
}
```

I tried to user `ngFor` inside mat-cell but its throwing error. I want to iterate over multiple roles of user and display it inside a single row in the column

Comment: May I suggest a better title to the question? It might get more views. Second, if you have an error, please include in the question, they normally prove helpful. But I'm going to guess that the error was to do with only being able to iterate over arrays not objects. Place your user object in an array and then use *ngFor.

Comment: @Steve I am now using *ngFor to iterate over array but I still can't display the data inside mat-cell                                                                                     <ng-container matColumnDef="roles">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Roles </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"  >
         <div *ngFor="let role of roles">{{role}} data</div> 
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After seeing your `ngFor` solution in the comments, it turns out you're iterating over the wrong variable. `roles` is not defined explicitly, it is within your user array. The `row` variable returns each object in the user array one by one so in order to access the `roles` in each `row`, you need to iterate over `row.roles`.

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="roles">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Roles </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let role of row.roles">
            {{role.roleName}}  
            <br /> <!-- Use br if you want to display the roles vertically -->
        </ng-container>
    </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```